# Add a 'submenu/folder' to the start menu in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, context-menu

I'm looking to do something very similar to .. [Add a submenu to the start menu in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/515235/add-a-submenu-to-the-start-menu-in-windows-7)

But i'm trying to be a bit more specific .. I have Notepad++ portable and 'another' program in a folder

I want to be able to see them the same as "Windows Virtual PC" and "Excel 2013" are listed in my image and Not pop a new window.

[image]

Comment: I don't really consider the question you linked to be that clear, so your question isn't that clear, you need to explain what you want exactly.  Any event, the menu your talking, is just expanding the contents of a folder which happens to have an icon.  The link question after 5 years doesn't have an answer because I would argue that what the author originally wanted wasn't clear.